# Gherkin, how to write a scenario where have optional given steps?

Tags: syntax, gherkin

I'm writing a simple add item scenario. This item have required fields (name, number, date) Also that item have optional fields (category, description). how i can specify the fields:

```
scenario: add item
   given name
   and  number
   and  date
   but category is not null
   and description is no null
   then save item
```

Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

I would split this into multipal scenarios, as each scenario should test one thing.

Also you should always have a When step. Given is a precondition and not always needed, When is an action and Then is the expected outcome of that action. Without a When step you are saying you have an expected outcome of doing nothing?

I would write the Feature File to be something like the following:

```
Feature: Add Item
    As a stock control manager
    I want to be able to add items to an inventory
    So that I have a catalogue of al items in stock

Business Rules:
    - Name, number and date are mandatory data
    - category and description are optional

Sceanrio: Add item witout category
    When I add an item without a category
    Then the Item will be saved

Sceanrio: Add item without descritpion 
    When I add an item without a descritpion 
    Then the Item will be saved

Sceanrio: Add item without name
    When I add an item without a name
    Then the item will not be saved
    And I will be informed the name is maditory

Sceanrio: Add item without number
    When I add an item without a number
    Then the item will not be saved
    And I will be informed the number is maditory

Sceanrio: Add item without date
    When I add an item without a date
    Then the item will not be saved
    And I will be informed the date is maditory
```

Comment: You might want to add a scenario with adding all data too, just for completeness.